# Powers mod prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> I want to find the powers of $2$, $2^{20}$ mod a prime $53$

Is there a way to simplify this problem? I know I could take $(2^{5})^4$ but this is already taking $32^4$ mod $53$ which isn't easy without a calculator.

Comment: Hint: $256=265-9$

Comment: Square $32$ ... mod $53$ ... square again (mod $53$) ... shouldn't take long ?

Comment: $32^4\equiv 21^4\equiv 441^2\equiv 17^2 \pmod{53}$, not that bad

Comment: Along the lines of the answers, but not sufficiently different to be an independent answer: $2^{10}=1024$, and $20\cdot 53=1060$ So $2^{10}\equiv -36 \bmod 53$. Then, $2^{20}\equiv (-36)^2\equiv 36\cdot 3\cdot 12\equiv 108\cdot 12\equiv 2\cdot 12\equiv 24 \bmod 53$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fleshing out a comment, it's easy to see that $2^8=256=265-9=5\cdot53-9\equiv-9$ mod $53$. Thus $2^{16}\equiv81\equiv28$ mod $53$, so $2^{17}\equiv56\equiv3$ mod $53$, so finally $2^{20}\equiv8\cdot3=24$ mod $53$.

The trick here is looking for "easy" steps that give small remainders mod $53$. The search for easy steps can take as much time as simply taking a brute-force (or, somewhat more slickly, a repeated squaring) approach, but can be fun (and instructive) in its own right.

**Added later**: Another way to get from $2^8$ to $2^{20}$ using $265\equiv0$ mod $53$ can be summarized as

$$2^8=256\equiv-9\implies2^{10}\equiv-36\equiv17\implies2^{20}\equiv289\equiv24$$

(This is similar to Bill Dubuque's derivation, but differs in the way the congruence $2^{10}\equiv17$ is obtained. It also assumes $17^2=289$ is an "easy" square.)

Comment: Easier to use $2^{10}$ as I explain in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Take the complement, factorize, and also keep the number small should do the trick.

\begin{align}
2^{20} &\equiv 32^4 \pmod{53} \\
&  \equiv (-21)^4 \pmod{53}\\
&\equiv 7^4 \cdot 3^4 \pmod{53} \\
&\equiv 49^2\cdot (81 - 53) \pmod{53}\\
&\equiv (-4)^2 \cdot(28) \pmod{53}\\
&\equiv 7 \cdot 4^3 \pmod{53}\\
&\equiv 7 \cdot (64-53) \pmod{53}\\
&\equiv (77-53) \pmod{53}\\
&\equiv 24 \pmod{53} 
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

To do this we can make use of the identity: `(a*b)%m = [(a%b)^2]%b`

If we say that `a=32^2=1024` and `b=53`, we get `[(1024%53)^2]%53`

`53 * 19 = 1007` which means that `1024%53=17`
Then we do `17^2=289`and `289%53 = 24`
Therefore your answer is 24.

Answer (score 1):

I happen to know that $2^{20}=1048576$, so I used long division to compute the remainder of $1048576\div53$ and got remainder $24$.  It really wasn't hard to do with pen and paper!

Answer (score 1):

$2^{21}\equiv 128^3 \equiv 22^3 \equiv 48 \pmod{53}$

Therefore $2^{20} \equiv 24 \pmod{53}$

Answer (score 1):

$\!\bmod \color{#c00}{53}\!:\ 2^{10}\! = 1024 =\! \overbrace{\color{#c00}{50}}^{\large\color{#c00}{-3}}(20)\!+\!24 \equiv 17\, $ $\Rightarrow 2^{20}\equiv 17^2\equiv 24$

Comment: Took $10$ secs of *mental* arithmetic, e.g. use $\, \large 17^2 = \color{#c00}{17}(\color{#c00}{3}(5)\!+\!2)\equiv \color{#c00}{-2}(5)\!+\!34\equiv 24\ \ $